# Query performance on AX vs StudioManagement

Tags: sql-server, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, query-performance, database-indexes

Sometimes, not always, I have a performance problem with some actions in our ERP, for example, when users finalize the shipment.

So, the only solution is rebuild indexes on inventdim table, but the indexes are not fragmented! :(

If I realize a trace I can see the execution plan is reading a lot of registers and takes a lot of time.
But if I realize the same query on my management Studio the query is automatic...

I can not understand what is the problem... :(
Indexes are not fragmented, stadistics are ok and not occurs allways....

Can you help me?

```
SELECT  A.ITEMID,B.CONFIGID 
FROM    INVENTSUM A,INVENTDIM B     
WHERE   A.DATAAREAID='ent' 
        AND A.CLOSED=0
        AND A.ITEMID='V69350032'
        AND B.DATAAREAID='ent'
        AND B.INVENTLOCATIONID='AT'
        AND B.WMSLOCATIONID='LFINAL2'
        AND B.WMSPALLETID='PA518295'
        AND A.INVENTDIMID=B.INVENTDIMID    
GROUP BY A.ITEMID,B.CONFIGID
ORDER BY A.ITEMID,B.CONFIGID
```

[Management Studio capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K91DV.jpg)

[Trace sql server capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxb6K.jpg)

Comment: Can you paste the text of the query and if possible an actual execution plan?

Comment: what happens when you add `option (recompile)` to the query

Comment: Is this dynamic SQL?  If so, is it built and executed within an SP?

Comment: What version of AX are you on? I've seen some versions with an old AX kernel choose the wrong index.

Comment: Our AX Version is AX 4.0 SP2

Comment: How can I add the option recompile in Axapta?? Is it possible?

Comment: That's not possible in Axapta to do `option (recompile)` and it's possible that AX is the problem. You can try adding `index XYZ` in the AX `select` statement to force what index it uses. I've had to do this in the past.